# How to edit "design/frontend/base/default/ template/customer/address/edit.phtml" in magento?

Tags: magento

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Edit customer address template
 *
 * @see Mage_Customer_Block_Address_Edit
 */
?>
<?php if($this->getTitle()): ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></h1>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSaveUrl() ?>" method="post" id="form-validate">
    <div class="fieldset">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <?php echo $this->getNameBlockHtml() ?>
            </li>

            <li class="wide">
                <label for="company"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCompany()) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text  <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" id="telephone" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="fax"><?php echo $this->__('Fax') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="fax" id="fax" title="<?php echo $this->__('Fax') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getFax()) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('fax') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Address') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">

        <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
            <li class="wide">
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getStreet($_i)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address %s', $_i) ?>" id="street_<?php echo $_i ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endfor; ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('customer/address')->isVatAttributeVisible()) : ?>
            <li class="wide">
                <label for="vat_id"><?php echo $this->__('VAT Number') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="vat_id" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getVatId()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('VAT Number') ?>" id="vat_id" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('vat_id') ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                           <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                        </select>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        //<![CDATA[
                            $('region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getRegionId() ?>");
                        //]]>
                        </script>
                        <input type="text" id="region" name="region" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="zip" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li<?php if($this->canSetAsDefaultBilling()) echo ' class="control"' ?>>
                <?php if($this->isDefaultBilling()): ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $this->__('Default Billing Address') ?></strong>
                <?php elseif($this->canSetAsDefaultBilling()): ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="primary_billing" name="default_billing" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Use as My Default Billing Address') ?>" class="checkbox" /><label for="primary_billing"><?php echo $this->__('Use as my default billing address') ?></label>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
            <li<?php if($this->canSetAsDefaultShipping()) echo ' class="control"' ?>>
                <?php if($this->isDefaultShipping()): ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $this->__('Default Shipping Address') ?></strong>
                <?php elseif($this->canSetAsDefaultShipping()): ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="primary_shipping" name="default_shipping" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Use as My Default Shipping Address') ?>" class="checkbox" /><label for="primary_shipping"><?php echo $this->__('Use as my default shipping address') ?></label>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <p class="back-link"><a href="<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->getBackUrl()) ?>"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a></p>
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Save Address') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Save Address') ?></span></span></button>

    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
    new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'zip');
//]]>
</script>``
```

i want to when i click on button then it create pop up box with ok button and when i am click on ok button the default procedure of magento will be continue.
and all that by using different model in local code pool.

it is possible??

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like that http://www.miniscript.it/demopages/confirmjquerydialog/demo.php and manage this action with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just add hidden block to the template, change default confirmation button to fake button and enable action:

```
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('hiddendivid').style.display = 'block'; return false;">
 Fake button opens div with true button
</button>

<div id="hiddendivid" style="display: none;">
 this is popup div

 <input type="submit" name="truemagentosubmit" value="This will real submit the form" />
 <input type="submit" value="Or close thos window" onclick="document.getElementById('hiddendivid').style.display = 'none'; return false;" />
</div>
```

all will work in the same form like a standard submit.